# How can I view PowerPoint files on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, keynote, ms-office

I want to play PowerPoint presentations on an iPad which I create on a computer, using MS Powerpoint 2010.

I know there is an Apple app for that, but it isn't free. So, are there any other apps or methods?

Comment: The Apple app is Keynote for iPhone and iPad, which costs US $9.99 in the App Store. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8

Comment: Does it matter if you want iPad or iPad 2 sharing features? (or is playing them solely so you can look at them directly on the iPad as one or two users looking at the screen together?)

Answer (score 3):

If you have only small amount of presentations, which you want to play on iPad, you can convert pptx file into jpg's or pdf's on PC and then upload it to iPad

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any free Power point viewer for iPad but I can suggest 2 solutions:

1. Transfer PowerPoint to PDF files:
   and use  pdf viewer to read your slide
2. Export PowerPoint slides as pictures

Answer (score 2):

If you get a [Windows Live](https://signup.live.com/) account (you can use any email address to open one, but you will already have one if you have a Hotmail account), you can upload your PowerPoint files to SkyDrive, where you can use the [**PowerPoint Web App**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) to view and even edit them.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) is an option. I tested this with a .ppt from my own machine and I was surprised by how well it works. Just upload your .ppt file to your Google Docs account (which in a modern browser can be done with a simple drag-and-drop) and then allow Google to convert the document:

[image]

Once it is uploaded you can view it from your iPad by visiting Google Docs. You might want to buy a 3rd party browser like [Atomic Web](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-browse/id347929410?mt=8) so you can view the presentation full-screen.